# Nodejs/express multiple get request not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router, endpoint

I am trying to call and especific with the route "/allPatientsAdm/" endpoint but its not working, call the first defined endpoint get with the route "/:id".

```
router.get('/:id', getPacientes);
router.get('/allPatientsAdm/', getAllPacientesAdmin);
router.get('patientById/:id', getPaciente);
router.post('/', postPaciente);
router.put('/:id', putPaciente);
router.delete('/:id', deletePaciente);
```

returns `router.get('/:id', getPacientes);` instead of `router.get('/allPatientsAdm/', getAllPacientesAdmin);`

when I define it first of all other endpoints works fine

```
router.get('/allPatientsAdm/', getAllPacientesAdmin);
router.get('/:id', getPacientes);
router.get('patientById/:id', getPaciente);
router.post('/', postPaciente);
router.put('/:id', putPaciente);
router.delete('/:id', deletePaciente);
```

Any idea of why this behavior?

Comment: Express treats `/allPatientsAdm/` the same as `/allPatientsAdm`, and that matches the `/:id` route. Since it tests the routes in order, this is treated as `:id = allPatientsAdm`. Best is to avoid ambiguous routes like this.